# Pandas DataFrame column another DataFrame when I'm expecting a Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame object called "design" which I construct from a DataFrame object called "df" like so:

```
design = df.loc[year, [DV] + IVs + controls].copy(deep=True)
```

where

```
"DV" = a string

"IVs" = list of strings 

"controls" = list of strings
```

When I then try to access a column of "design" I *usually* get a Series, as expected, and can use the .unique() method:

```
design[DV].unique()
```

^ works fine, usually.

However, *sometimes*, when I use a different combination of DV, IVs, and controls, design[DV] is a DataFrame (which doesn't have a .unique() method). I'm stumped as to why.

Any ideas?

Note: Maybe this is important? Sometimes "controls" is an empty list. Sometimes the lists contain strings that are unicode.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

@AndyHayden, here's an example:

design = DataFrame with one column-duplicate ('SPKATH'):

DV = 'LETDIE1'

```
ipdb> design.columns Index([u'LETDIE1', u'SUICIDE1', u'REGION', u'AGE', u'SEX', u'RACE', u'DEGREE', u'INCOME', u'RELIG', u'RELITEN', u'ATTEND', u'POLVIEWS', u'SPKATH', u'SPKCOM', u'SPKATH'], dtype=object)
```

When I call design[DV].unique() I get an error:

```
> /home/misha/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.12.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.‌​egg/pandas/core/frame.py(2088)__getattr__() 2087 raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % -> 2088 (type(self).__name__, name)) 2089 

ipdb> a 

self = <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> 

Index: 1530 entries, 1977.0 to 1977.0 

Data columns (total 1 columns): LETDIE1 1530 non-null values dtypes: float64(1) 

name = unique
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One situation where this occurs is if you have **duplicate** columns, that is, DV is in IVs or controls. For example:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=list('ABC'))

In [12]: df_a = df.loc[:, list('ABB')]

In [13]: df_a
Out[13]:
   A  B  B
0  1  2  2
1  4  5  5

In [14]: df_a['A']  # a Series
Out[14]:
0    1
1    4
Name: A, dtype: int64

In [15]: df_a['B']  # a DataFrame
Out[15]:
   B  B
0  2  2
1  5  5
```

One way to get around this is to select by position:

```
In [16]: df_a.iloc[:, 1]  # always a Series
Out[16]:
0    2
1    5
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Andy, thanks so much! My DataFrame did indeed contain duplicates, but, the column I wanted (DV) was not duplicated. 

To use your example above, it is as if df_a['A'] returned a DataFrame when the duplicates 'B's were present, but, when when I removed them, i.e. del df_a['B'], then df_a['A'] returned a Series, just as I wanted. Hope what I'm trying to say makes sense. If not, I can describe what's happening specifically in my data.

Comment: Andy, I wavered between accepting/unaccepting a bit because while your comment solved my problem, it wasn't quite a ..direct (not sure what word to use) solution. In my data calling df_a['A'] returned a DataFrame, _even though column 'A' was not duplicated_. Getting rid of duplicate 'B' columns made df_a['A'] return a Series, as I wanted. That behavior seems strange to me, but luckly I didn't need the duplicate 'B' columns. so I was happy to delete those to get the behavior I want. Anywhom, accepted the answer, and thanks for saving me hours of bebugging!!!

Comment: @DrMisha that's really weird, can you post a minimal example that demonstrates it? (could be a bug, so maybe best to post on github here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/new)

Comment: Andy, I added an example to the OP.

Comment: update to 0.13.1 and see if this is still an issue, if it is you should post a bug report on github: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues (Please provide a minimal example frame so we can replicate this)